# How do I delete a kivy object and variables held within a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, memory-management, kivy

I created code which places Kivy objects and all their variables in a dataframe. The idea was once the object has served its purpose I can drop the row from the dataframe and delete the object from memory.

**The simplified example below will require a -pip install of Kivy and creation of the .kv file specified**. In the example an object is generated on app initialisation. A count is incremented with the u key. Once the count reaches the y seed value of the object in the dataframe that row is dropped from the dataframe. However, the object remains on screen. The code prints the counter value and dataframe to track what is happening.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
    
import pandas as pd
from kivy.graphics import Color, Quad
    
    
class GUI(RelativeLayout):
    """Variable creation"""
    """Y axis setting"""
    vertical_lines = 10
    vertical_line_spacing = 1

    """X axis setting"""
    horizontal_line_count = 10
    horizontal_line_spacing = 1

    """Object settings"""
    seed_count = 1
    objects = pd.DataFrame()
    counter = -1


    """Initialise app"""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        """GUI creation"""
        self.create_objects()
        self.update_objects()

        """Keyborad bindings"""
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self.keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)

    def keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'u':
            self.counter += 1
            self.destroy_objects()
            print("counter at: ", self.counter)
            print(self.objects['y seed'])
        return True


    def create_objects(self):
        """Create vertical lines"""
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 1, .8)
            for i in range(self.seed_count):
                data = {'element 1': Quad(), 'element 2': Quad(),
                        'x seed': 0, 'y seed': i}
                creation = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
                self.objects = self.objects.append(creation)

        return self.objects


    def update_objects(self):

        for i in range(self.seed_count):
            element_1 = self.objects['element 1'].iloc[i]
            element_2 = self.objects['element 2'].iloc[i]
            y_spacing = self.vertical_line_spacing * self.width
            x_spacing = self.horizontal_line_spacing * self.height
            xmin, ymin = self.objects['x seed'].iloc[i], self.objects['y seed'].iloc[i]

            x1a, y1a = (xmin, ymin)
            x2a, y2a = (xmin - y_spacing / 2, ymin + x_spacing)
            x3a, y3a = (xmin + y_spacing * 1.5, ymin + x_spacing)
            x4a, y4a = (xmin + y_spacing, ymin)

            x1b, y1b = x2a, y2a
            x2b, y2b = x1a, ymin + 2 * x_spacing
            x3b, y3b = x4a, ymin + 2 * x_spacing
            x4b, y4b = x3a, y3a

            element_1.points = [x1a, y1a, x2a, y2a, x3a, y3a, x4a, y4a]
            element_2.points = [x1b, y1b, x2b, y2b, x3b, y3b, x4b, y4b]

    def destroy_objects(self):
        try:
            for i in range(len(self.objects)):
                if self.objects['y seed'].iloc[i] < self.counter:
                    self.objects = self.objects.drop(self.objects.index[i])
        except IndexError:
            pass


class ExampleApp(App):
    pass
    
    
ExampleApp().run()
```

This requires the following .kv file to run:

```
GUI:

<GUI>:
```

I think the problem may relate to dataframes creating copies of themselves rather than writing over the origonals.

How can I delete the object while still maintaining the DataFrame structure?

Is there a better way to manage objects and related variables to allow for editing and deleting en mass?

Comment: one of the most unique questions I have seen.  I'd look at the Widget class.  you need to know the parent of your object and use the_parent.remove_widget(child_object) method using an object reference.  also, it looks like there may be some code formatting problems in your GUI class.  some lines are not indented.?

Comment: Thanks for you comment and appologies for the initial error in the code. I spend a good hour simplfying my code to a managable segment for stack overflow. I basically have a game where moving an object into a boundary causes its deletion.


Anyway I tried the following before dropping the line:
   self.canvas.remove(self.objects['element 1'].iloc[i])

This didnt throw an error, the controls relating to the object cease working but the rendered object remains on screen.

Is this the method you were thinking of?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23968080/2397865   that question is related to yours.  The code is not saving 'objects' so much as graphics instructions so you may need to consider how you could clear or draw things again.  I don't have experience with this kind of activity.    There is a line in which you create a dict with Quad() and Quad() and this is what causes graphics on the screen but since the arguments are the same, both get created over the top of each other.  I don't think pandas is very related to your question.  you could consider re-writing with a List to simplify for general use

Comment: Hi Mark, I ended up doing just that and forgetting about pandas altogether! This means you have a slightly more complex delete function as it requires a while loop to change the index and lost length in the fly.

Comment: Did you isolate your problem to being specifically Pandas-related by the switch to a list?  then perhaps you could get an answer by writing a very tiny, specific, runnable code that illustrates the issue.  tag a post with pandas and maybe someone with deeper experience could help.  you could look up weakref; study that topic

Comment: Hi Mark, I think the issue was a copy based issue. You're right that weakref could be a solution. My motivation for using a dataframe was the simplicity of editing en mass. Maybe careful control of the dataframe copying could 
also be implemented, however, I tried being extremely explicit with this and it didn't seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reverted to using lists to store objects.

Objects can be cleared with the canvas.remove() command and variable information can be deleted from lists iteratively. This means you can only delete one at a time when you iteratre through the list which is why I avoided it in the first place.

Using a while loop to contain the delete query counters indexing errors by shrinking the index on the fly.

Comment: # using set() to perform task
set1 = set(test_list)
set2 = set(remove_list)
res = list(set1 - set2)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but may be runnable code that will work within one file.  It converts the Pandas to a list just to simplify the reading for a wider audience.  The original code was missing the build() method.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout

from kivy.graphics import Color, Quad


class GUI(RelativeLayout):
    """Variable creation"""
    """Y axis setting"""
    vertical_lines = 10
    vertical_line_spacing = 1

    """X axis setting"""
    horizontal_line_count = 10
    horizontal_line_spacing = 1

    """Object settings"""
    seed_count = 5

    counter = -1

    """Initialise app"""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.objects = []
        """GUI creation"""
        self.create_objects()
        self.update_objects()

        """Keyboard bindings"""
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self.keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)

    def keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'u':
            self.counter += 1
            self.destroy_objects()
            print(f"counter at: {self.counter}")
            print(self.objects)
        return True

    def create_objects(self):
        """Create vertical lines"""
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, .5, .5)
            for i in range(self.seed_count):
                data = {'element 1': Quad(), 'element 2': Quad(),
                        'x seed': 0, 'y seed': i}
                Color(0, 1, .5, .5)
                self.objects.append(data)
        # return self.objects

    def update_objects(self):

        for one_object in self.objects:
            element_1 = one_object['element 1']
            element_2 = one_object['element 2']
            y_spacing = self.vertical_line_spacing * self.width
            x_spacing = self.horizontal_line_spacing * self.height
            xmin, ymin = one_object['x seed'], one_object['y seed']

            x1a, y1a = (xmin, ymin)
            x2a, y2a = (xmin - y_spacing / 2, ymin + x_spacing)
            x3a, y3a = (xmin + y_spacing * 1.5, ymin + x_spacing)
            x4a, y4a = (xmin + y_spacing, ymin)

            x1b, y1b = x2a, y2a
            x2b, y2b = x1a, ymin + 2 * x_spacing
            x3b, y3b = x4a, ymin + 2 * x_spacing
            x4b, y4b = x3a, y3a

            element_1.points = [x1a, y1a, x2a, y2a, x3a, y3a, x4a, y4a]
            element_2.points = [x1b, y1b, x2b, y2b, x3b, y3b, x4b, y4b]

    def destroy_objects(self):
        ones_to_remove = []
        try:
            for one_object in self.objects:
                if one_object['y seed'] < self.counter:
                    ones_to_remove.append(one_object)
        except IndexError:
            pass

        # finally 'destroy'
        for one in ones_to_remove:
            self.objects.pop(one)
        print(f"{self.objects} and the length is {len(self.objects)}")


from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
GUI:

''')


class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI()
    pass


ExampleApp().run()
```